# Find $S_1^2+S_2^2+S_3^2+...+S_{2n-1}^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, geometric-progressions

**Question**: If $S_1,S_2,S_3,...,S_n$ be the sums of $n$ infinite G.P. series respectively whose first terms are respectively $1,2,3,...,n$ and common ratios $\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},...,\frac{1}{n+1}$ respectively, then find the value of $S_1^2+S_2^2+S_3^2+...+S_{2n-1}^2$.

**My attempt**:

$S_k=\frac{k}{1-\frac{1}{k+1}}$

$\implies S_k=k+1$

$\implies S_k^2=(k+1)^2$

$\implies S=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n-1}S_k^2$

$\implies S=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n-1}(k+1)^2$

$\implies S=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n-1}(k^2+1+2k)$

$\implies S=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n-1}(k^2)+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n-1}(1)+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n-1}(2k)$

$\implies S=\frac{(2n-1)(2n)[2(2n-1)+1]}{6}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ +(2n-1)+\frac{2(2n-1)(2n)}{2}$

$\implies S=\frac{(4n^2-2n)(4n-1)}{6}\;\;\;+2n-1+4n^2-2n$

$\implies S=\frac{16n^3-4n^2-8n^2+2n}{6}\;\;+2n-1+4n^2-2n$

$\implies S=\frac{16n^3-4n^2-8n^2+2n-6+24n^2}{6}$

$\implies S=\frac{16n^3+12n^2+2n-6}{6}$

$\implies S=\frac{8n^3+6n^2+n-3}{3}$

**My problem**: The correct answer is $\frac{n(2n+1)(4n+1)}{3}$ which on simplification gives $\frac{8n^3+6n^2+n}{3}$. Where have i gone wrong? Please help.

Comment: Your calculations seem correct

Comment: Out of curiosity, $S_k$ seems to have only been defined for $1\le k\le n?$

Comment: the answers are off by 1, which could be explained if the "correct" answer was obtained by summing from 0 instead of 1 (which is of course wrong)

Comment: A quick check will easily confirm that "correct answer" of $\frac {n(2n+1)(4n+1)}3$ is incorrect, as it returns $5$ for $n=1$, where the answer should be $4$ as $S_1^2=\left(\frac 1{1-\frac 12}\right)^2=4$. The actual answer should be one less than the "correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{r=1}^{2n-1}S_r^2&=\sum_{r=1}^{2n-1}\left(\frac r{1-\frac 1{r+1}}\right)^2\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^{2n-1}(r+1)^2\\
&=\sum_{r=2}^{2n}r^2\\
&=\frac 16 (2n)(2n+1)(4n+1)-1\\
&=\boxed{\frac {n(2n+1)(4n+1)}3}-1\\
&=\frac {8n^3+6n^2+n-3}3\\
&=\frac {(2n-1)(4n^2+5n+3)}3\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$
\begin{align}
(k+1)^2
&=(k+1)k+(k+1)\\
&=2\binom{k+1}{2}+\binom{k+1}{1}
\end{align}
$$
we have
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_k\binom{2n-1-k}{2n-1-k}\left[2\binom{k+1}{k-1}+\binom{k+1}{k}\right]
&=2\binom{2n+1}{2n-2}+\binom{2n+1}{2n-1}\\
&=\frac{8n^3+6n^2+n}3
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, leaving out the $k=0$ term, we get
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1}(k+1)^2=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{8n^3+6n^2+n-3}3}
$$